# angular component load multiple time when ngModel is added in template

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create angular form.
I have referenced the form in that angular module.

The problem is when i add ngModel in input textbox, the angular component loads multiple times in the page.

Following is the **module** code

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HeaderProfileComponent } from './header-profile.component';
import { LayoutModule } from '../../../../layouts/layout.module';
import { DefaultComponent } from '../../default.component';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UserService } from '../../../../../_services/user.service'; 
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        "path": "",
        "component": DefaultComponent,
        "children": [
            {
                "path": "",
                "component": HeaderProfileComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule,CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes), LayoutModule 
    ], exports: [
        RouterModule
    ], declarations: [
        HeaderProfileComponent
    ],providers:[
        UserService
    ]
})
export class HeaderProfileModule {
}
```

following is the **component code**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Helpers } from '../../../../../helpers';
import { UserService } from '../../../../../_services/user.service';
import { ApplicationUser } from '../../../../../Entities/UserDetail';

@Component({
    selector: ".m-grid__item.m-grid__item--fluid.m-wrapper",
    templateUrl: "./header-profile.component.html",
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class HeaderProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    appUser: ApplicationUser = null;
    newUser: ApplicationUser = null;
    constructor(private _userService: UserService) {
        this.appUser = new ApplicationUser();
        this.newUser = new ApplicationUser();
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this._userService.getCurrentUser()
            .subscribe((data: ApplicationUser) => {
                this.appUser = data;
            }, (err: Response) => {

            });
    }
    createUser(){
        debugger;
    }
}
```

in angular component HTML:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="createUser()" class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right">
                                    <input class="form-control m-input" type="password" [(ngModel)]="newUser.FirstName" >

    </form>
```

Wen i add only without mgNodel, it works fine.

Comment: How do you mean it loads multiple times? Where? Where are you declaring HeaderProfileComponent to exist? Please recreate an example plnkr to help us help you.

Comment: HeaderProfileComponent is added in module class in the first code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior was due to theme i was using.
Theme handled the exceptions and never throw in console so angular tried to load the component even after exceptions caused this behavior.

Removed the code block and let angular throw in browser shows input should contain name attribute with ngModel , adding attribute -> Fixed